# python group by two columns, extract first element by one index

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, multi-index

If I use groupby function, e.g. `Data.groupby(['id','company']).size()`, it will give a result like:

```
id   company 
1    a        2
     b        3
     c        6
2    d        1
     e        5
```

but how can I extract the numbers `[2,1]` (the first elements of each zeroth-index-level-group, according to the sorted order of the first-index-level-group)?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're after. Do you want a list of the first size in each group?  (The result would depend on how `company` sorts.)  The smallest size?  Do you want the sizes of `(1, a)` and `(2, d)` in particular?

Comment: I just wanna extract the size number(column 3) of the first company in the same id. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let:

```
agg_df = Data.groupby(['id','company']).size()
```

*Assuming you want the result from the first entry for each group of elements having the same value for the zeroth level of the MultiIndex, and that each group is sorted by the first index level as you prefer. (After the updated comment, this appears to be the desired output)*

```
unique_zeroth_level = dict(agg_df.index.values).keys()
group_first_vals = [
    agg_df.select(lambda x: x[0]==idx_val, axis=0).head(1).values[0] 
    for idx_val in unique_zeroth_level]
```

*Assuming you're asking for the unique elements of the zeroth level of the resulting MultiIndex*

In this particular case, since the returned result is a Series, you can make use of a trick using `unstack`:

```
agg_df.unstack(level=0).columns.values
```

or use a `dict` constructor

```
dict(agg_df.index.values).keys()
```

*Assuming you want the result for `(1, 'a')` and `(2, 'd')` in particular, and that you want to access them by the index values (not just as a consequence of those being the lexicographically first entries in their respective groups)*

```
agg_df.ix[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'd')]]
```

Comment: Yes, I wanna "Assuming you want the result from the first entry for each group of elements having the same value for the zeroth level of the MultiIndex, and that each group is sorted by the first index level as you prefer. " 
I used a more complex loop too, but looking for a fast way to do that. And your code works! Thank you!

Comment: I might have done something like `agg_df.reset_index().groupby(["id"]).first()[0].tolist()`, but the `unstack` trick is nice.

Comment: Yes, for small data, reindex is much quicker than dict constructor, but i didnt test for the big data yet. Thank you!